# What are some approaches to networking with colleagues in different teams?

Tags: communication, work-environment, colleagues

I am currently dealing with trust issues concerning my interpersonal skills. I unintentionally ruined the strong relationship with my manager at the office. My senior is aiming for a higher position at the office. He is pursuing a stronger relationship with both my manager and other team members. He has succeeded and has a good relationship with the manager now.

In the coming year, the company will need to promote one person instead of two. But I also have to chance to move to another department.

I'm having difficulty connecting with people outside my department. I tried to reach out but I couldn't fit in their team.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to reach but I couldn't fit in their squad

It's not immediately obvious to me what that means lol but they're in the same physical office as you then I'd suggest you invite one of them out to lunch. If the day you propose doesn't work for them and they don't propose another day don't get discouraged - just ask another person in that department and another and another until you find someone you can do lunch with. And just develop a dialog / rapport with them.

And don't ask rapid fire. If one person says no then give it a week or so before asking the next person. If nobody says yes you can either take that as a hint or loop back around and re-ask the person you had originally asked.